# TypeError: cannot substract different models: 'res.partner()' and 'res.users()' in odoo 15

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

TypeError: cannot substract different models: 'res.partner()' and 'res.users()'

After recent git pull from Odoo version 15.0, i am getting error to open sales orders and also some other custom object records.

I am not getting where exactly is occuring this error, is it any bug or what in recent version of odoo 15?

I am copying full error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cicindela/V15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/home/cicindela/V15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 698, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/cicindela/V15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 368, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cicindela/V15/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cicindela/V15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 357, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/cicindela/V15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 921, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/cicindela/V15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 546, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/cicindela/V15/cicindela/deep/edoo_custom_treeview/controllers/main.py", line 12, in call_kw
    call_kw_result = super(LvmController, self).call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs, path)
  File "/home/cicindela/V15/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 546, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/cicindela/V15/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1324, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/cicindela/V15/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1316, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/cicindela/V15/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 460, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/cicindela/V15/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 433, in _call_kw_model
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/cicindela/V15/odoo/addons/web/models/models.py", line 571, in search_panel_select_range
    comodel_records = Comodel.search_read(comodel_domain, field_names, limit=limit)
  File "/home/cicindela/V15/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 5044, in search_read
    records = self.search(domain or [], offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order)
  File "/home/cicindela/V15/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 1810, in search
    res = self._search(args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, count=count)
  File "/home/cicindela/V15/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/res_users.py", line 559, in _search
    return super(Users, self)._search(args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, count=count,
  File "/home/cicindela/V15/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 4711, in _search
    query = self._where_calc(args)
  File "/home/cicindela/V15/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 4467, in _where_calc
    return expression.expression(domain, self).query
  File "/home/cicindela/V15/odoo/odoo/osv/expression.py", line 442, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "/home/cicindela/V15/odoo/odoo/osv/expression.py", line 668, in parse
    dom = HIERARCHY_FUNCS[operator](left, ids2, model)
  File "/home/cicindela/V15/odoo/odoo/osv/expression.py", line 576, in parent_of_domain
    records = records[parent_name] - records.browse(parent_ids)
  File "/home/cicindela/V15/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 5799, in __sub__
    raise TypeError(f"cannot substract different models: '{self._name}()' and '{other._name}()'")
```